# Calculate progress based on possible paths (JavaScript Questions)

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to workout remaining questionnaire progress without bouncing the progress bar percentage back every time there is more questions added.

End goal scenario:

User enters questionnaire, they're on question one there is 4 questions to answers the progress bar is split in to 4. The user gets to `question 3` but by clicking option 2 on `question 3` now adds 2 extra questions to answer. The progress bar should stay at the current percentage but work out the remaining percentage based on 3 answers.

Hope the above scenario makes sense.

Below is a very rough idea of what I have so far:

```js
// Questions
let questions = {
    1: {
        title: "Title",
        firstQuestion: true,
        options: [{
            tooltip: "",
            nextQuestion: 2
        }, {
            tooltip: "",
            nextQuestion: 2
        }, {
            tooltip: "",
            nextQuestion: 10000
        }]
    },
    2: {
        title: "Title",
        options: [{
            tooltip: "",
            nextQuestion: 3
        }, {
            tooltip: "",
            nextQuestion: 3
        }, {
            tooltip: "",
            nextQuestion: 3
        }, {
            tooltip: "",
            nextQuestion: 3
        }]
    },
    3: {
        title: "Title",
        options: [{
            tooltip: "",
            nextQuestion: 4
        }, {
            tooltip: "",
            nextQuestion: 4
        }, {
            tooltip: "",
            nextQuestion: 4
        }]
    },
    4: {
        title: "Title",
        options: [{
            tooltip: "",
            nextQuestion: 13
        }, {
            tooltip: "",
            nextQuestion: 5
        }]
    },
    5: {
        title: "Title",
        options: [{
            tooltip: "",
            nextQuestion: 6
        }, {
            tooltip: "",
            nextQuestion: 6
        }, {
            tooltip: "",
            nextQuestion: 6
        }, {
            tooltip: "",
            nextQuestion: 10000
        }]
    },
    6: {
        title: "Title",
        options: [{
            tooltip: "",
            nextQuestion: 7
        }, {
            tooltip: "",
            nextQuestion: 7
        }, {
            tooltip: "",
            nextQuestion: 7
        }, {
            tooltip: "",
            nextQuestion: 7
        }, {
            tooltip: "",
            nextQuestion: 14
        }]
    },
    7: {
        title: "Title",
        options: [{
            tooltip: "",
            nextQuestion: 17
        }, {
            tooltip: "",
            nextQuestion: 17
        }, {
            tooltip: "",
            nextQuestion: 17
        }, {
            tooltip: "",
            nextQuestion: 17
        }, {
            tooltip: "",
            nextQuestion: 17
        }]
    },
    8: {
        title: "Title",
        options: [{
            tooltip: "",
            nextQuestion: 9
        }, {
            tooltip: "",
            nextQuestion: 9
        }, {
            tooltip: "",
            nextQuestion: 9
        }]
    },
    9: {
        title: "Title",
        options: [{
            tooltip: "",
            nextQuestion: 10
        }, {
            tooltip: "",
            nextQuestion: 10
        }, {
            tooltip: "",
            nextQuestion: 10
        }]
    },
    10: {
        title: "Title",
        options: [{
            tooltip: "",
            nextQuestion: 11
        }, {
            value: "Roof",
            attribute: "Flue Exit",
            tooltip: "",
            nextQuestion: 15
        }]
    },
    11: {
        title: "Title",
        options: [{
            tooltip: "",
            nextQuestion: 12
        }, {
            tooltip: "",
            nextQuestion: 12
        }]
    },
    12: {
        finalQuestion: true,
        input: true,
        placeHolder: 'e.g SWS'
    },
    13: {
        title: "Title",
        options: [{
            tooltip: "",
            nextQuestion: 6
        }, {
            tooltip: "",
            nextQuestion: 6
        }]
    },
    14: {
        title: "Title",
        options: [{
            tooltip: "",
            nextQuestion: 7
        }, {
            tooltip: "",
            nextQuestion: 7
        }, {
            tooltip: "",
            nextQuestion: 10000
        }]
    },
    15: {
        title: "Title",
        options: [{
            tooltip: "",
            nextQuestion: 12
        }, {
            tooltip: "",
            nextQuestion: 12
        }]
    },
    17: {
        title: "Title",
        options: [{
            tooltip: "",
            nextQuestion: 8
        }, {
            tooltip: "",
            nextQuestion: 8
        }, {
            tooltip: "",
            nextQuestion: 8
        }, {
            tooltip: "",
            nextQuestion: 8
        }, {
            tooltip: "",
            nextQuestion: 8
        }]
    },
    // Errors
    10000: {
        isError: true,
        title: "Finally, what is the first part of your postcode?",
        error: "Postcode"
    }
};

// Answers filled in
let answersPath = [1, 2, 3];

// Find the max valid answer
function maxValidAnswer () {
    let objectKeys = Object.keys(questions).filter(x => {
    return questions[x].error == undefined
  });
      
  return objectKeys.length;
}

// Calculate Percentage
function calculateAnswers () {
    const myBar = document.getElementById('myBar'); 
  const lastAnswerFilled = Math.max.apply(Math, answersPath);
  const percentage = ((lastAnswerFilled / maxValidAnswer()) / 100) * 10000;

  
  myBar.style.width = `${percentage}%`;
  myBar.innerHTML = `${percentage}%`
}

calculateAnswers();
```

```css
#myProgress {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ddd;
}

#myBar {
  width: 10%;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #04AA6D;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="myProgress">
  <div id="myBar"></div>
</div>
```

**After speaking in comments**

The best scenario would be to generate all possible paths and work out the progress based on already selected questions vs possible path. Possible paths like this solution but based on questions: https://nsisodiya.medium.com/find-all-paths-from-point-1-to-n-algorithm-problem-solving-with-javascript-9de778a22243?source=follow_footer---------4----------------------------

Comment: so you want to calculate the percentage of answered questions versus the total amount of questions, which can change if the user selects option 2 on question 3?

Comment: @AlphaHowl exactly that :) - what i thought about is running through the questions building a array of all valid paths which a user can take and then calculating the progress bar based on valid questions remaining if that makes sense?

Comment: That is a good idea. What I was thinking is maybe you could raise an event (using `window.dispatchEvent`) every time you go to a new question. The event listener function should then check how many questions there are in total, and how many have been answered, and hence calculate the progess. Would this be possible?

Comment: @AlphaHowl that is very possible with the idea of having the valid paths. Do you have an idea of how you can work out all the possible paths? e.g. looping through the questions to build possible paths. I know you can do it for nodes e.g. graphs like following: https://nsisodiya.medium.com/find-all-paths-from-point-1-to-n-algorithm-problem-solving-with-javascript-9de778a22243?source=follow_footer---------4----------------------------

Comment: Ahhh i see, OK. So for each path there would be a different number of total questions.

Comment: @AlphaHowl Exactly that, you have any ideas how that can be achieve to find all possible paths?

Comment: I'll look into it now.

Comment: @AlphaHowl - Thanks Alpha! :)

Comment: No problem :)   .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found an easier way instead of finding the possible paths, which was going to get a little complicated. I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for but to me it looks like it works.

Basically, I used Js Sets to eliminate questions which are higher than the current one, and find the number of questions which have a higher key than the current one.

Here is how that works:

```js
let questions = {
    1: {
        title: "First, question?",
        firstQuestion: true,
        options: [{
            value: "Option 1",
            tooltip: "",
            nextQuestion: 2
        }, {
            value: "Option 2",
            tooltip: "",
            nextQuestion: 2
        }, {
            value: "Other",
            tooltip: "",
            nextQuestion: 300
        }]
  }, 
  2: {
        title: "second question",
        options: [{
            value: "Option 1",
            tooltip: "",
            nextQuestion: 3
        }, {
            value: "Option 2",
            tooltip: "",
            nextQuestion: 3
        }, {
            value: "Other",
            tooltip: "",
            nextQuestion: 300
        }]
  },
  3: {
        title: "third question",
        options: [{
            value: "Option 1",
            tooltip: "",
            nextQuestion: 6
        }, {
            value: "Option 2",
            tooltip: "",
            nextQuestion: 4
        }, {
            value: "Other",
            tooltip: "",
            nextQuestion: 300
        }]
  },
  4: {

        title: "third question",
        options: [{
            value: "Option 1",
            tooltip: "",
            nextQuestion: 5
        }, {
            value: "Option 2",
            tooltip: "",
            nextQuestion: 5
        }, {
            value: "Other",
            tooltip: "",
            nextQuestion: 300
        }]
  },
  5: {
        title: "third question",
        options: [{
            value: "Option 1",
            tooltip: "",
            nextQuestion: 6
        }, {
            value: "Option 2",
            tooltip: "",
            nextQuestion: 6
        }, {
            value: "Other",
            tooltip: "",
            nextQuestion: 300
        }]
  },
  6: {
        title: "fourth question",
        options: [{
            value: "Option 1",
            tooltip: "",
            nextQuestion: 2
        }, {
            value: "Option 2",
            tooltip: "",
            nextQuestion: 7
        }, {
            value: "Other",
            tooltip: "",
            nextQuestion: 300
        }]
  },
  7: {
        title: "Well done!",
        options: [{
            value: "Start over",
            tooltip: "",
            nextQuestion: 1
        }],
        error: true
  },
  300: {
    error: true
  }
};

const question_prompt = document.getElementById("question_prompt");

// Answers filled in
let answersPath = [0];

// Find the max valid answer
function maxValidAnswer () {
    let objectKeys = Object.keys(questions).filter(x => {
    return questions[x].error == undefined
  });
      
  return objectKeys.length;
}

// Calculate Percentage
function calculateAnswers () {
    const myBar = document.getElementById("myBar"); 
  const lastAnswerFilled = Math.max.apply(Math, Array.from(answersPath));
  const percentage = ((lastAnswerFilled / maxValidAnswer()) / 100) * 10000;

  
  myBar.style.width = `${percentage}%`;
  myBar.innerHTML = `${percentage}%`
}



let current_question_number = 1;
function render_question() {
    let current_question = questions[current_question_number];
    let title_html = `<h1>${current_question.title}</h1>`;
    let options_html = ``;

    current_question?.options?.forEach(option => {
        options_html += `<button next-question="${option.nextQuestion}">${option.value}</button>`;
    });

    question_prompt.innerHTML = title_html + options_html;

    let path_array = Array.from(answersPath);
        if(Math.max.apply(Math, path_array) > current_question_number) {
            path_array = path_array.map(x => {
                return x < current_question_number ? x : null;
            });
        }
        answersPath = new Set(path_array);
        answersPath.delete(null);
        calculateAnswers();
}




window.addEventListener("click", e => {
    let target = e.target;
    if(target.nodeName == "BUTTON" && target.getAttribute("next-question") != null && target.closest("#question_prompt")) {
        let path_array = Array.from(answersPath);
        if(Math.max.apply(Math, path_array) > current_question_number) {
            path_array = path_array.map(x => {
                return x < current_question_number ? x : null;
            });
        }
        answersPath = new Set(path_array);
        answersPath.delete(null);
        answersPath.add(parseInt(current_question_number));
        calculateAnswers();
        current_question_number = target.getAttribute("next-question");
        render_question();
    }
});


render_question();

calculateAnswers();
```

```css
#myProgress {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ddd;
}

#myBar {
  width: 10%;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #04AA6D;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Questions</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>


<div id="myProgress">
  <div id="myBar"></div>
</div>

<div id="question_prompt"></div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Ps: please note systems like this can be considered undecidable. So our algorithm can only guess the progress. Here's why:

Even if we used the other method - finding all possible paths, we would not know which path to use because we do not know which path the user will chose to go down - which depends on the user's choice of which option to click on.
Consider we have paths of:

- Question number: 1,3,5,7
- Question number: 1,3,4,5,7

When the user is at Q3, which path should the computer use? Will the user chose option1, leading to Q5, or option2, leading to Q4? If they chose option1, the progress will be higher than if they chose option2, leading to Q4. The computer has to wait and see which option the user picks, and then recalculate the progress once an option is picked.

Comment: Hey - if i run the example above and press option 1, option 1 and option 1. It never gets to the last question, if you then change option 1 question 3 to goto the 4th answer it stays at 50% complete. It never gets to 100%

Comment: It becomes completed when you go to the very last "question" or screen, i.e. question number 7. So you should set `nextQuestion` to `7`, like it is done for option2 on "fourth question".

Comment: When you hit fourth question, it should be more than 50% because when you click next option it would be 100% as it would be questionnaire finished

Comment: This is called an undecidable problem. Imagine that the other option (`option1`) leads to another question, Q4.1, which has all its options lead to Q4.2, which has all its options lead to Q4.3, and so on. In this case, the progress would depend on which option the user will chose - something which will happen in the future, so the computer cannot calculate this. What it **can** calculate - and in this case, what it **is** calculating - is what percentage of questions have been answered out of the grand total of questions, some of which will never be visited. This is a bit like the Game of Life

Comment: So based on what you're saying, I will need the final question be higher than the others. I've just update my original question code with how my questions are in my demo environment. They jump to different questions but the final question being number "12"

Comment: Yeah, as you say the final question needs to be higher than the rest. I just edited the answer to summarise our discussion.